# Module 'opencvpluginsample' is not installed in the Kurento Media Server

Tags: kurento

**What I Did:**

1. I downloaded the updated opencv_plugin-sample from the https://github.com/Kurento/kms-opencv-plugin-sample.
2. Run the cmakelist using the cmake-gui and generated the so using

   ```
   sudo make install
   ```
3. The so is generated in the path

   ```
   usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/kurento/modules
   ```
4. From the js folderin the kms-opencv-plugin-sample,i run the command

   ```
   cmake .. -DGENERATE_JS_CLIENT_PROJECT=TRUE
   ```
5. To generate the  "kurento-module-opencvpluginsample.min.js", "kurento-module-opencvpluginsample.map" file i installed grunt in the js folder,using the command

   npm install grunt grunt-browserify grunt-contrib-clean grunt-jsdoc grunt-npm2bower-sync minifyify
6. A dist folder is generated which contain the file("kurento-module-opencvpluginsample.min.js", "kurento-module-opencvpluginsample.map","kurento-module-opencvpluginsample.js")
7. I created a folder for kms-opencv-client and copied all the files from the kurento-crowddetector folder from the link https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-js
8. In the kms-opencv-client ,inside bower-component,I replaced the kurento-crowddetector-module with the opencv-plugin-sample-module which contains the js generated from step:6
9. Also changed the js path in the index.html and also replaced the module name in index.js
10. I started the Kurento media server and and also http server
11. When i loaded the page from the browser

    http://10.10.1.3:8080/index.html?ws_uri=ws://10.10.1.3:8888/kurento#
12. When i click the start button,the following error occurs

    SyntaxError: Module 'opencvpluginsample' is not installed in the Kurento Media Server

    **Did i miss anything in the opencv-plugin instalation process**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that js client is trying to check all modules that you require and it seems that this module is not installed correctly in kurento mediaserver.

You say that you generated the .so file, but you also need to let mediaeserver load it. For this, you have three options:

1. Install it at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/kurento/modules/
2. Edit /etc/default/kurento and add KURENTO_MODULES_PATH variable to indicate the directory where your so file is loaded
3. Indicate the installation directory to cmake correctly by executing: `cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr && make && sudo make install`

Once this is done, the kms logs should show that the module is being loaded.

Comment: Now the local stream is working,the remote stream not loaded because in crowd detector they use

   const RegionOfInterest = kurentoClient.register.complexTypes.RegionOfInterest
   const RegionOfInterestConfig = kurentoClient.register.complexTypes.RegionOfInterestConfig
   const RelativePoint= kurentoClient.register.complexTypes.RelativePoint

Comment: In the kms-opencv-plugin-sample ,it has three method
       OpencvPluginSampleOpenCVImpl::process (cv::Mat &mat)
    OpencvPluginSampleOpenCVImpl::setFilterType (int filterType)
    OpencvPluginSampleOpenCVImpl::setEdgeThreshold (int edgeValue)
    
    How to replace the opencv-plugin-sample method with the crowd detector method in index.js

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the question, and also it seems not to be related with the original topic.

Comment: yes,if you get a chance pls join the room http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36966/kurento-media-server