# Change Opencv version 2.4.8 to 3.0.0 in KMS

Tags: kurento

**What i did:**

1.With reference to the link https://github.com/Kurento/kms-opencv-plugin-sample and [Module 'opencvpluginsample' is not installed in the Kurento Media Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36005376/5176361) ,I run the opencv sample in Kurento Media Server

2.Also successfully run few opencv projects like **FaceDetection**

3.The projects which I have builded are using opencv 3.0.0 .So I am trying to change the opencv version in KMS to 3.0.0

4.In the *CMakelist.txt* from the kms-opencv-plugin-sample,I changed the line

```
        set (OPENCV_REQUIRED 3.0.0)
```

But opencv 2.4.8 libraries are in the link.txt file

5.I also tried to manually delete the opencv2.4.8 libraries and replace it with the opencv 3.0.0 libraries in   ***/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu*** ,But the Opencvpluginsample is not installed.

**What i have to know:**

1.Is it possible to change the opencv version in KMS?

2.Is there any specific way to change the opencv version in KMS or What are the changes I have to do to change the Opencv version from 2.4.8 to 3.0.0 in KMS?

**Updates:**

1.I added the opencv3.0.0 include in the ***kms-opencv-plugin-sample/src/server/implementation/objects*** path ,so that now I can able use opencv3.0.0 in process method.

2.But when I remove the opencv 2.4.8 still the error occurs in gstreamer-1.5 *libopencvfilter.so*,which using the opencv 2.4.8

Now whether I can able change the opencv version in gstreamer?If yes,how to do it?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: @Seraf .I worked on kurento  a year back,i think i have done that,but didnt remember that.sry.

Answer (score 0):

first of compile .so file for opencv3.0.0 version then update it inside kms cmakelist.